# Some assignment operators don't work in AngularJS expressions.. why not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, assignment-operator

The AngularJS docs only list four differences between Angular expressions and JS expressions ([docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularexpressionsvsjsexpressions)):

1. Attribute evaluation (against scope instead of global window);
2. Forgiving (to `undefined` and `null`);
3. No control flow statements allowed;
4. Filters (results of expression evaluation can be passed through filter chain).

But arithmetic assignment operators also don't work inside an expression. For example, "plus-equals" `+=` and "minus-equals" `-=` raise an error on the constant after the equals-sign.

Is there a particular reason why these assignment operators would be problematic to allow in expressions? Or would this simply be a matter of implementation priorities?

Is there perhaps an Angular-specific way of incrementing and decrementing? Currently, people seem to be left to typing the full `somelongname = somelongname + x`, or defining increment and decrement as functions in a controller. The same goes for other arithmetic assignment operators.

A short example of what I'm using to increment and decrement as workaround. It works, but is it elegant?

In controller:

```
$scope.incr = function(number, constant){
    $scope[number] += constant;
};
$scope.decr = function(number, constant){
    $scope[number] -= constant;
};
```

In HTML:

```
<button class="btn" ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="decr('currentPage', 1)">
```

Comment: You seem to be referring to angular view expressions (the stuff you can do within {} tags in the actual view). Angular allows some stuff to happen in the view, but prefers for most of the heavy-lifting to happen in the controller, directives or services. Maybe if you explained what you're trying to achieve in view expressions, we can give a better answer.

Comment: The terminology is quite clear in the docs:"Expressions are JavaScript-like code snippets that are usually placed in bindings such as `{{ expression }}`. Expressions are processed by the $parse service." What I'm trying to achieve is to increment and decrement number variables in `$scope` by `ng-click="..."`. If I understand correctly, expressions given in `{{...}}` and as directive values (such as of `ng-click`) are evaluated similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a particular reason why these assignment operators would be problematic to allow in expressions? Or would this simply be a matter of implementation priorities?

I would say it is a combination of

1. implementation priorities (see [Brad and Igor video talking about expression support](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W13qDdJDHp8&t=27m28s) in v1.2) and
2. what @Sharondio mentioned in the comment above: the view is normally not the place for expressions – the controller is.